# JDBC SQL Database is locked?

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I am writing a program that uses a local SQL database to store data.

I am using the driver found here: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

I am trying to read from the database and put the contents of tableName into a JTable like this:

```
public Object[][] getTable(String tableName){
    int columns = getColumnNumber(tableName);
    int rows = getRowNumber(tableName);
    String[] columnNames = getColumnNames(tableName);
    Object[][] table = new Object[rows][columns];
    try{
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbName + ".db");
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
            rs.next();
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
                table[r][c] = rs.getString(columnNames[c]);
            }
        }
        return table;           
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERROR CREATING TABLE ARRAY");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then later I try to come back and add a row to the table:

```
public boolean addRow(String tableName, Object[] values){
    if(!isDataAcceptable(tableName, values))
        return false;
    try{
        String stmt = "insert into " + tableName + " values (";
        for(int c = 0; c < values.length; c++){
            if(values[c] instanceof String)
                stmt += "'" + values[c] + "'";
            else
                stmt += values[c];
            if(c == (values.length - 1))
                    stmt += ");";
            else
                stmt += ", ";
        }
        System.out.println(stmt);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbName + ".db");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(stmt);
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERROR INSERTING ROW");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I then want to update the JTable I created before with the new row.

When I try to add the row however it causes an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
```

that points to the line:

```
statement.executeUpdate(stmt);
```

...in the addRow() method.

Why is the database locked and how do I unlock it to write to it?

Comment: You don't close any of the objects you create, neither the `ResultSet` nor the `Statement` nor the `Connection`. I would suspect that that is your problem.

Comment: I am extremely new to SQL and assumed that since they were local resources they would close when the method ended. How do I close them?

Comment: Like any other external resource is Java you need to call `close()` on then when you're done. The `try finally` pattern is usually used.

Comment: I added .close() to all the methods that open a Connection or a ResultSet and that fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the database locked and how do I unlock it to write to it?

The database is most likely locked in `addRow` because the previous call to `getTable` did not close the resultset.  The code also fails to close the database connection objects which will cause a resource leak.

The basic fix is to call `close()` on the `rs` and `connection` objects, but you need to do it the right way to make your code reliable.

Here's the recommended way to do it in Java 7 using "try with resources" syntax:

```
try (Connection connection = 
         DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbName + ".db"),
     Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(),
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName)) {
  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    rs.next();
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      table[r][c] = rs.getString(columnNames[c]);
    }
  }
  return table;           
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR CREATING TABLE ARRAY");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

You can also do this by calling `close` explicitly in a `finally` block, but it is more verbose, and the code can be difficult to get right if you have related resources that need to be closed ... like here.

Answer (score 0):

close the database and reopen it and try,
sometimes database queries running in background.