# SQL exception locked database

Tags: java, sql, forms, netbeans

I have a problem in adding data into the database when i run this code error will appear "java.sql.SQLException:database is locked" how can i fix this?

```
 try{

 String sql="Insert into account(id,fname,lname,username,password) values(?,?,?,?,?)";

 pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
 pst.setString(1, txtId.getText());
 pst.setString(2, txtFname.getText());
 pst.setString(3, txtLname.getText());
 pst.setString(4, txtUsername.getText());
 pst.setString(5, txtPassword.getText());

 pst.execute();

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Saved"); 
 }
     catch(SQLException e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); 
 }
     finally{
     try{
          rs.close();
         pst.close();
     }
     catch(SQLException e){

 }
 }
```

Comment: What other code is running at this time? What's the context? I suspect you have a transaction running else where that's block this command.

Comment: are you closing the connection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593170/jdbc-sql-database-is-locked

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: im using sqlite I manage to fix it i had to close the connection to my login page